# Imagemap links aren't showing up

Tags: html, css, image, imagemap

I'm trying to have a fully responsive resizable image of a map with some image map links on it, a simple page.

But I can't get this to work after already trying countless time, not even with some scripts it worked, but using the correct percentage values for coordinates I think it should work but not sure why they won't show up.
I'm a html newbie, just trying to do this for a hobby project. But surely it is possible?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://r4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/222/498/544/abstract-ancient-antique-art-wallpaper-ed9498c67de1d4a3a5e6a63f97c0653e.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 10vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.content map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 44;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PNcPCR3/breeland.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
  <map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Farm" title="Farm" href="https://i.ibb.co/PNcPCR3/breeland.jpg" coords="53.41%, 29.21%, 42.45%, 34.07%" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="hhhggdfg45 " title="hhhggdfg45 " href="https://i.ibb.co/PNcPCR3/breeland.jpg" coords="89.02%, 57.16%, 11.15%, 76.29%" shape="rect">
</map>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the main part looks responsive to me when I resize but do you also want the nav to turn horizontal with width: 100% on mobile view?

Comment: Image map coordinates must be valid floating point numbers, not percentages. "The coords attribute must, if specified, contain a valid list of floating-point numbers."

Comment: Not that important to be perfect on mobile but the most important is to get the image map links to show up. Or.. do they show up for you and that's something strange on my end? Well, I tried with coordinates as non percentages but they aren't responsive then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you cannot make this responsive in this way without Javascript. (I'm also a bit of a beginner, so don't pin me down on this) This is because the coords have to be specific points on your image that cannot be defined with percentages.

However, you **can** use alternative means.

If you throw traditional image mapping out the window, and just put your image in a div that's 100% width and position:relative, you can then add smaller divs to that div that are position:absolute. Those you **can** position with percentages. I'm fairly sure you can also size those with percentages. Then you add the links to those divs, and you've got yourself a responsive alternative to the image map.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it's troublesome to set up. Well, you're sure more knowledgeable than me, for me it's basically like the first time ever doing this. But, in that case, wouldn't you know of a java script option that would work? It's fine if coordinates aren't percentages. I tried java script once, image maps scaled properly, but the result was problematic because the image didn't and was being cut off vertically beyond window, glued to left/right rather than top/bottom. But maybe that's just me and couldn't figure it out. Here is link to that earlier attempt: https://ufile.io/ydlcc8xw

Comment: I don't have much experience with JavaScript yet, but I did find this article that might be helpful to you: https://www.madcapsoftware.com/blog/how-to-implement-responsive-image-maps-in-your-html5-outputs/

Comment: Many thanks, I finally managed to figure it out based on this article and its links.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. I managed to add the Farm on the map area.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(https://r4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/222/498/544/abstract-ancient-antique-art-wallpaper-ed9498c67de1d4a3a5e6a63f97c0653e.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar ul {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    flex-flow: inherit;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
}

img {
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    zoom: .4;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: inherit;
    align-items: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PNcPCR3/breeland.jpg" usemap="#image-map" />
        <map name="image-map">
            <area alt="Farm" title="Farm" href="#" coords="1790,790,2220,940" shape="rect">
        </map>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was already there, mate. The problem is this effectively made the image non responsive, even though the image map link appears.